# FileNotFoundError after deployment

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have written a web app in Django that works fine locally.
After deploying it, trying to access a pdf throws an error **FileNotFoundError**.

- settings.py

  `PDF_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'report/static/media/pdfs')`
- model.py

  `pdf = models.filePathField(path=settings.PDF_DIR)`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Share the complete traceback, and the code that causes the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More info needs for answering your question, but few parameters important to handle files:

1. You can only serve files that is in static or media directories(except handle files directly out of programming by some web-server configurations)
2. You must prepend `STATIC_URL` or `MEDIA_URL` to `pdf` and make final url, example in template:

`<a hred="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{mymodel.pdf}}"> » Download « </a>`